# php, nested ul/li list from list of strings

Tags: php, html-lists

`$items = array ('page 1', 'page 2', 'page 3', 'page 4');`

```
<ul>
    <li>page 1
        <ul>
            <li>page 2
                <ul>
                    <li>page 3
                        <ul>
                            <li>page 4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have simple list of things and i would like to have it to nested ul/li list. How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want ? You're creating one-elements lists for each of your items. That doesn't look right.

Comment: What do you want the final page to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily handle this using function and recursion, see example below:

```
$items = array ('page 1', 'page 2', 'page 3', 'page 4');
recursive($items);
function recursive($items)
{
    if (is_array($items) && !empty($items)) {
        echo "<ul><li>";
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo array_shift($items);
            recursive($items);
            break;
        }
        echo "</li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/550199

Answer (score 0):

Normal `<ul><li>` can be achive by using this:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($arr as $kVal){
echo "<li>".$kVal."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

But in your scenario

it could be done something like this:

```
foreach($arr as $kVal){
  echo "<ul><li>".$k;
}
```